# How to make a Child table to access another table laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.1.

I have Three Table.

- Films
- Videos
- Video Category

User can create a film and add many videos, but every video should belong to any one category (example. Making Video, Trailer Video, Film Events).

Now i want to fetch all films,video and video category of each video by passing a Film ID.

**Table structure**

**Films Table**

```
filmID | filmName 
-----------------
   1   |  Film 1
   2   |  Film 2
```

**Video Table**

```
videoID | filmId | catID | videoURL
-----------------------------------
   1    |    1   |  cat1 |   URL 1
   2    |    1   |  cat2 |   URL 2
```

**Video Category Table**

```
  catID  | category
--------------------
   cat1  |  Trailer
   cat2  |  Making
   cat3  |  Events
```

I can get All the Videos by passing FilmID

```
{
  filmId: "filmName",
  filmName: "Film Name",
  coverPhoto: "image URL",
  created_at: "2015-06-28 06:35:26",
  updated_at: "2015-06-28 06:35:45",
  videos: [
      {
        id: 7,
        filmId: "filmID",
        videoCategory: "trailer",
        videoUrl: "h41Jb29P4",
        created_at: "2015-06-28 11:40:22",
        updated_at: "2015-06-28 11:40:22"
      }
  ]
}
```

But how to i get the Video Category along with this output. Something like this

```
{
      filmId: "filmName",
      filmName: "Film Name",
      coverPhoto: "image URL",
      created_at: "2015-06-28 06:35:26",
      updated_at: "2015-06-28 06:35:45",
      videos: [
          {
            id: 7,
            filmId: "filmID",
            videoCategory: "trailer",
            videoUrl: "h41Jb29P4",
            created_at: "2015-06-28 11:40:22",
            updated_at: "2015-06-28 11:40:22"
            videoCategory: [
                  {
                     videoCategoryId: "1",
                     videoCategoryName: "Trailer"
                  }
            ]
          }
      ]
    }
```

Is there any way to do without passing multiple queries and merge in PHP?

Please anyone Help me.

Comment: Yes i myself found the answer. I used Nested Eager loading Concept in Laravel http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

Yes i myself found the answer. I used Nested Eager loading Concept in Laravel

[Laravel 5 Eager Loading does this job correct](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading)